# Spring Data Mongodb : Deserialize using builder

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I'm wondring if there's a way to configure spring data to use a builder to deserialise a document. Something like `JsonPOJOBuilder` or `JsonDeserialize(builder = ADocumentBuilder)` for jackson ?

In fact I'm using lombok with `@SuperBuilder` annotation like :

```java
@Data
@RequiredArgConstrcutor
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AttachementBase {
  private String a;
  private final String b; //maybe final
  private String c;
}
```

```java
@Value
@SuperBuilder
@Document
public class Attachement extend AttachementBase{
  private String d;
}
```

Evething's works fine with the builder and how to use it, except when calling the `AttachementRepository.findXX()` Spring trys to call a constructor but it cannot find the appropriate one.

Lombok generates `AttachementBuilder` in the `Attachement` class and I want to use it to deserialise this document.

I do not want this post be related to lombok, i juste illustrated the use case. The question is how to use a builder to deserialize a document in Spring-data-mongodb ?

Comment: I don't now If I have well understood your case but maybe wrapping your builder in a hand written constructor annotated with `@PersistenceConstructor` could make it without forgetting to remove a noArgsConstructor from your document

Comment: can you show me ? i do not get you, sorry